# No current connection to Database - java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: java, multithreading, derby

I'm trying to create an multithreaded app (Java) in which some threads insert further rows to database. I use Embedded Derby from JDK.

This is code that concerns establishing connection to database and inserting.

```
public class DatabaseConnection
{
private static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:./Database/DB;create=true;user=fafejs;password=fafejs";
private Connection conn;
private DatabaseUpdateContent duc;
private DatabaseUpdateView duv;

public synchronized void createConnection()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"); // load the driver
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL); // make Derby JDBC connection
        duc = new DatabaseUpdateContent(conn);
        duv = new DatabaseUpdateView(conn);
        System.out.println(conn);
    }
    catch (Exception except) // TODO - obsluga
    {
        except.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public synchronized void recreateConnection()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
        duc = new DatabaseUpdateContent(conn);
        duv = new DatabaseUpdateView(conn);
        System.out.println("Reconnect:" + conn);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public boolean updatePlayer(PlayerService player)
{
    try
    {
        int ID = player.getID();
        String firstName = player.getFirstName();
        String lastName = player.getLastName();
        Date birthdate;
        if(!(player.getDate() == null))
            birthdate =  new java.sql.Date(player.getDate().getTime());
        else
            birthdate = null;
        String league = newLeagueName(player.getLeagueName()).toUpperCase();
        String team = player.getTeamName();
        int apps = player.getApps();
        int firstSquad = player.getFirstSquad();
        int minutes = player.getMinutes();
        int goals = player.getGoals();
        int yellowCards = player.getYellowCards();
        int redCards = player.getRedCards();
        duc.updatePlayersTable(ID, firstName, lastName, birthdate);
        duc.updateLeagueTable(league, ID, team, apps, firstSquad, minutes, goals, yellowCards, redCards);
        return true;
    }
    catch (SQLException sqlExcept)
    {
        //shutdown();
        sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public synchronized void shutdown()
{
    try
    {
        DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL + ";shutdown=true");
        conn.close();
        //System.gc();
    }
    catch (SQLException sqlExcept)
    {
        //sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}


public void updatePlayersTable(int ID, String firstName, String lastName, Date birthdate) throws SQLException // z klasy DatabaseUpdateContent
{
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE APP.PLAYERS SET FIRST_NAME = ?, LAST_NAME = ?, BIRTHDATE = ? WHERE ID = ?");
    pstmt.setString(1,firstName);
    pstmt.setString(2,lastName);
    pstmt.setDate(3,birthdate);
    pstmt.setInt(4,ID);
    if(pstmt.executeUpdate() == 0)
    {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO APP.PLAYERS VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        pstmt.setInt(1, ID);
        pstmt.setString(2, firstName);
        pstmt.setString(3, lastName);
        pstmt.setDate(4, birthdate);
        pstmt.execute();
    }
    pstmt.close();
}
public void updateDB() // procedura, która zajmuje się aktualizacją zawartości bazy danych
{
    DatabaseConnection database = new DatabaseConnection();
    database.createConnection();
    for(PlayerService player: players)
    {
        while(!database.updatePlayer(player))
        {
            database.recreateConnection();
        }
    }
    database.shutdown();
}
```

On the whole, strongly most rows are inserted to appropriate table properly, but sometimes i get SQLNonTransientConnectionException:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No current connection.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.noCurrentConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.checkIfClosed(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.setupContextStack(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at DatabaseService.DatabaseUpdateContent.updateLeagueTable(DatabaseUpdateContent.java:39)
at DatabaseService.DatabaseConnection.updatePlayer(DatabaseConnection.java:68)
at DataService.TeamService.updateDB(TeamService.java:66)
at DataService.TeamService.getPlayers(TeamService.java:56)
at DataService.TeamService.getPlayersUrls(TeamService.java:44)
at DataService.LeagueService.getTeams(LeagueService.java:52)
at DataService.LeagueService.run(LeagueService.java:35)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: ERROR 08003: No current connection.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
... 17 more
java.sql.SQLException: Database './Database/DB' not found.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleDBNotFound(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
at DatabaseService.DatabaseConnection.recreateConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:35)
at DataService.TeamService.updateDB(TeamService.java:69)
at DataService.TeamService.getPlayers(TeamService.java:56)
at DataService.TeamService.getPlayersUrls(TeamService.java:44)
at DataService.LeagueService.getTeams(LeagueService.java:52)
at DataService.LeagueService.run(LeagueService.java:35)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: ERROR XJ004: Database './Database/DB' not found.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
... 20 more
```

This exception occurs many times in a row, because if updating player fails, function updatePlayer will return false and we repeat loop in function updateDB. But after a while (about 50 attempts of inserting row), it's possible to establish connection and insert a row.

Certainly i've looked for solution of this problem. I tried way associated with System.gc(), what is suggested in some documentation but it doesn't help in my case.

I was considering also fact that my problem could be connected with multithreading of my app but in Embedded Derby's documentation they say in short that Embedded Derby should deal with it.

Thanks for your support in advance.

EDIT

This is error information that I get after adding code from http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain:

```
----- SQLException -----
SQLState:   08003
Error Code: 40000
Message:    No current connection.
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No current connection.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.noCurrentConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.checkIfClosed(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.setupContextStack(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at DatabaseService.DatabaseUpdateContent.updatePlayersTable(DatabaseUpdateContent.java:17)
at DatabaseService.DatabaseConnection.updatePlayer(DatabaseConnection.java:73)
at DataService.TeamService.updateDB(TeamService.java:64)
at DataService.TeamService.getPlayers(TeamService.java:53)
at DataService.TeamService.getPlayersUrls(TeamService.java:39)
at DataService.LeagueService.getTeams(LeagueService.java:50)
at DataService.LeagueService.run(LeagueService.java:36)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: ERROR 08003: No current connection.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
... 17 more
java.sql.SQLException: Database './Database/DB' not found.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleDBNotFound(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
at DatabaseService.DatabaseConnection.recreateConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:39)
at DataService.TeamService.updateDB(TeamService.java:67)
at DataService.TeamService.getPlayers(TeamService.java:53)
at DataService.TeamService.getPlayersUrls(TeamService.java:39)
at DataService.LeagueService.getTeams(LeagueService.java:50)
at DataService.LeagueService.run(LeagueService.java:36)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: ERROR XJ004: Database './Database/DB' not found.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
... 20 more
```

It seems to me that error associated with not finding database (to be more precise, I mean problem connected with loading the driver of Embedded Derby) is caused by SQLNonTransientConnectionException and there is the rub.

Comment: Start by making sure you're seeing the **full** error information: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: Done and I get the same error information except this: 
  SQLException
  SQLState:   08003
  Error Code: 40000
  Message:    No current connection.

Comment: Assuming what you say is true (though you didn't update your message to show the complete information, just the truncated error stack), if the core problem is "Database './Database/DB' not found", the problem is that the folder named "Database/DB" is not found in the current directory of your program. That's what "./Database/DB" is: it's a relative directory path to the folder on your hard disk where your database is stored.